# Template array initialization with a list of values

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

In standard c++ we can write :

```
int myArray[5] = {12, 54, 95, 1, 56};
```

I would like to write the same thing with a template :

```
Array<int, 5> myArray = {12, 54, 95, 1, 56};
```

assuming that

```
template <class Type, unsigned long N>
class Array
{
public:

    //! Default constructor
    Array();

    //! Destructor
    virtual ~Array();

    //! Used to get the item count
    //! @return the item count
    unsigned long getCount() const;

    //! Used to access to a reference on a specified item
    //! @param the item of the item to access
    //! @return a reference on a specified item
    Type & operator[](const unsigned long p_knIndex);

    //! Used to access to a const reference on a specified item
    //! @param the item of the item to access
    //! @return a const reference on a specified item
    const Type & operator[](const unsigned long p_knIndex) const;

private:

    //! The array collection
    Type m_Array[N];
};
```

I thinks it is not possible but may be there's a tricky way to do it !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution is to write a class template that accumulates all the values which get passed to the constructor. Here is how you can initizalize your `Array` now:

```
Array<int, 10> array = (adder<int>(1),2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

The implementation of `adder` is shown below with complete demonstration:

```
template<typename T>
struct adder
{
   std::vector<T> items;
   adder(const T &item) { items.push_back(item); }
   adder& operator,(const T & item) { items.push_back(item); return *this; }
};

template <class Type, size_t N>
class Array
{
public:

    Array(const adder<Type> & init) 
    {
         for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
         {
               if ( i < init.items.size() )
                   m_Array[i] = init.items[i];
         }
    }
    size_t Size() const { return N; }
    Type & operator[](size_t i) { return m_Array[i]; }
    const Type & operator[](size_t i) const { return m_Array[i]; }

private:

    Type m_Array[N];
};

int main() {

        Array<int, 10> array = (adder<int>(1),2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < array.Size() ; i++ )
           std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

See the online demo at ideone yourself : http://www.ideone.com/KEbTR

Answer (score 2):

This becomes possible in C++0x using [initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Initializer_lists). Currently, there is no way to do this.

The closest you can get without this is to use [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/assign/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very trivial; just remove the constructors and
make the data members public.  The template issue is a red
hering; the same rules apply as for any class: if it is an
aggregate, you can use aggregate initialization; if it's not,
you can't.

-- 
James Kanze

Comment: If I set the data members as public this will break the access security implemented by the template class.

Comment: @chris Yes.  If hiding the elements is critical, then you can't use this format.  In a lot of cases, the array is part of the abstraction, so making it public is no issue.  In others, the array is totally hidden, so even wanting to use aggregate initialization is a violation of the abstraction.  In the cases between those two extremes, you're a bit stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution which doesn't need `adder` class template. Now you can do this:

```
int main() {

        Array<int, 10> array;
        array = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10;
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < array.Size() ; i++ )
           std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Here is the complete solution: http://www.ideone.com/I0L1C

Comment: @nawaz ideone link is broken. could you post the code? thanks

Comment: @Koushik: I've posted two solutions. See the other one which has the implementation of the `Array`. You can use that and experiment yourself on ideone. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz Actually i think i know how you have implemented but just wanted to be sure so.:-) very nice and this is the first time i saw anyone overloading ,.+1.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. This is not possible with current standard C++. However, with the next standard (c++0x) initializer-lists will do just that!