# Is it possible to construct the elements of a member array depending on an integral template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Assume:

```
template<class T,int N>
struct A {
  A(): /* here */ {}

  T F[N];
};
```

I need the elements of `F[]` to be constructed with `{0,1,2,...,N-1}`. If possible I would like to avoid recursively defined template structs with defining the last level as `template<class T> struct A<T,0>` and doing some complicated template tricks. Can C++11 initializer lists help?

This is similar [Template array initialization with a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375597/template-array-initialization-with-a-list-of-values), but it does not construct the elements with the increasing value. It sets it later in a run-time loop.

Comment: why can't array<T,N> be used here ?

Comment: It can, but doesn't solve this issue

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a variadic value template and constructor delegation:

```
template<int... I> struct index {
    template<int n> using append = index<I..., n>; };
template<int N> struct make_index { typedef typename
    make_index<N - 1>::type::template append<N - 1> type; };
template<> struct make_index<0> { typedef index<> type; };
template<int N> using indexer = typename make_index<N>::type;

template<class T, int N>
struct A {
  template<T...I> A(index<I...>): F{I...} {}

  A(): A(indexer<N>{}) {}

  T F[N];
};
```

This uses the sequence pack generator from [Calling a function for each variadic template argument and an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030538/c11-calling-a-function-for-each-variadic-template-argument-and-an-array?lq=1)

Comment: Is the use of `using` essential to the solution?

Comment: @Frank no, it can always be replaced by `typedef`.  It's just convenient in this case.

Comment: I voted up - I love how templates can be completely unreadable in the new standard ;-)

Comment: @Pawel: A bit of formatting would've helped a ton, and maybe even [another implementation of the indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:indices).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming some kind of [indices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/726300) solution is available:

```
A(): A(make_indices<N>()) {}

// really a private constructor
template<int... Indices>
explicit A(indices<Indices...>)
    // Can be an arbitrary expression or computation, too, like
    // (Indices + 3)...
    : F {{ Indices... }}
{}
```

If your compiler doesn't support delegating constructors, one option is to switch to `std::array<T, N>` and use a private static helper that returns an initialized array, such that the default constructor would become:

```
A(): F(helper(make_indices<N>())) {}
```

This would of course incur an additional (move) construction.

Comment: [Complete demo on LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9894e8cb01d5f7af1bbbef5e04397a16).

Comment: Is this `using` entirely necessary. My compiler GCC 4.6 doesn't understand it

Comment: @Frank You can introduce type synonyms with `typedef` as well.

Comment: If I do so, I get: error: type ‘A<int, 10>’ is not a direct base of ‘A<int, 10>’

Comment: @Frank 4.6 doesn't support delegating constructors.

Comment: Last question: What kind of thing is `return {};` ? Never seen this before. Does it return whatever is the return type by calling the default constructor?

Comment: @Frank Same braces as in `T t = {};`. Try to search for 'uniform initialization'.