# could not convert from <brace-enclosed initializer list>

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

It works for `struct RS : public JV<T,1>` but not for `struct RS : public JV<T,2>`.

```
error: could not convert ‘{(0, j), (0, j)}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘WJ<float>’
```

Do I have to overload `operator,()` ?
Code:

```
#include<iostream>

struct B {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct indices {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct build_indices
  : build_indices<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct build_indices<0, Is...> : indices<Is...> {};

template<class T,int N>
struct JV {

  JV(B& j) : JV(j, build_indices<N>{}) {}
  template<std::size_t... Is>
  JV(B& j, indices<Is...>) : jit(j), F{{(void(Is),j)...}} {}

  B& jit;
  T F[N];
};

template<class T>
struct RS : public JV<T,2>
{
  RS(B& j): JV<T,2>(j) {}
};

template<class T>
struct WJ
{
  WJ(B& j) {
    std::cout << "WJ::WJ(B&)\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  B j;
  RS<WJ<float> > b2(j);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the extra `{}` if you want to use a plain array `F{(void(Is),j)...}`. Or change it to `std::array<T, N> F` like you said.

A plain array simply uses `{}` for initialization, however and `std::array` is an aggregate which contains an array, so it uses the double braces.

See [Using std::array with initialization lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192185/using-stdarray-with-initialization-lists) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is an extra pair of `{}` braces.  Change

```
  JV(B& j, indices<Is...>) : jit(j), F{{(void(Is),j)...}} {}
```

to

```
  JV(B& j, indices<Is...>) : jit(j), F{(void(Is),j)...} {}
```

and it works fine.

The reason it works with `std::array` is that `array` is an aggregate *containing* an actual array:

```
// from 23.3.2.1 [array.overview]
namespace std {
  template<typename T, int N>
  struct array {
...
    T elems[N];    // exposition only
```

So to initialise `array`, an extra pair of braces is required compared to initialising an *actual* array.  gcc allows you to omit the extra braces, but complains:

```
  std::array<int, 3>{1, 2, 3};
```

> warning: missing braces around initializer for 'std::array::value_type [3] {aka int [3]}' [-Wmissing-braces]

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like they can only omitted in the form `T x = { a };`.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing

```
 T F[N];
```

with

```
 std::array<T,N> F;
```

did the trick! It seems `std::array` can do more than C arrays.

Comment: It's not necessarily that `std::array` can do more than C-style arrays, it's just that the initialization behaves differently. C-style need only one pair of braces, while `std::array` is an aggregate (thus allowing `{...}` initialization even in C++03). The second pair of braces is for the inner C-style array member.